# Shift cells after delete in excel defined Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with shifting cells in excel defined table.
When i had normal data just with filters on column headers this function worked ok :

```
If Not DeleteCells Is Nothing Then DeleteCells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
```

DeleteCells is Range consisting of cells found to be deleted across the worksheet.

Now im downloading data from power query and it became Excel defined Table with the name of Query1
and now when im turning deletion macro it shows error :
[image]

<sup>Error message: This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.</sup>

Is there a way to restore deletion and shifting functionality for table ?

Data looks like this

[image]

And lets say cells with a data needs to be cleared and remaining data needs to be shifted so the integrity of data remains so it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can occur because you are trying to delete cells where the shifting would deform the table.

For example, in the table below, let's say I try to delete cell C5.

[image]

I'll get an error message because after deleting and shifting to the left, the table would be distorted like the image below (this screenshot was edited to illustrate the point):

[image]

One way to avoid this issue is to delete the whole column instead.

```vb
Range("C5").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
```

This way the whole table will shift to the left which is allowed.

[image]

If you can't delete the whole column, you need to at least make sure that all cells in a table will be displaced by the same amount. For instance, this could also work in my example:

```vb
Range("C5:C7").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
```

And if that's not possible with the way your sheet is setup, then perhaps consider moving the table somewhere else or use `ClearContent` or something similar instead of deleting the cells.

Comment: "moving the table somewhere else or use ClearContent" what to you mean by moving table somewhere else ? I cannot remove whole columns.  i have 20 columns with data. and when macro runs it usually has to delete 1 cell data in each row and shifting is needed to keep integrity of data so it can be loaded into the system later on

Comment: I meant moving it somewhere in the same sheet where the table rows won't be affected by the shifting or into another sheet if possible. But looking at the edits you made to the question, I see that you are deleting cells *inside* the table, so the solutions in this answer don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... i figured out the solution was more simple than i initially thought.
Since excel table is a ListObject, after loading data through power query i just wrote short macro that .unlist the table and all my functionality that worked, works again !

```
Code:
Sub ConvertTableToRange()
 
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Query1")
    .Unlist                           ' convert the table back to a range
End With
```